# Integral closure of $\mathbb Z[i]$ in $\mathbb Q[i]$ the set of elements in $\mathbb Q[i]$ which satisfy a monic polynomial over $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, definition

The integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q$ the set of elements in $\mathbb Q$ which satisfy a monic polynomial over $\mathbb Z$. This is $\mathbb Z$.

The integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q[i]$ the set of elements in $\mathbb Q[i]$ which satisfy a monic polynomial over $\mathbb Z.$ This is $\mathbb Z[i]$.

The integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 3]$ the set of elements in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 3]$ which satisfy a monic polynomial over $\mathbb Z$. This is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$.

> **Is the integral closure of $\mathbb Z[i]$ in $\mathbb Q[i]$ the set of elements in $\mathbb Q[i]$ which satisfy a monic polynomial over $\mathbb Z[i]$? In other words, is it the set of elements in $\mathbb Q[i]$ which satisfy a monic polynomial in $\mathbb Z[i][x]$?**
>
> **What is the integral closure of $\mathbb Z[i]$ in $\mathbb Q[i]$? In other words, what elements in $\mathbb Q[i]$ satisfy a monic polynomial whose coefficients are in $\mathbb Z[i]$?**

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of integral closure.

Comment: If $R$ is a subring of a field $K$, and $S$ is the integral closure of $R$ in $K$, then $S$ is the integral closure of $S$ in $K$ ($S$ is *integrally closed*).

Comment: Does it make sense to talk about the algebraic closure of of $R$ in $F$? For example the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: algebraic closure is only for field